# How to optimize update query with calculation on MySQL with big data

Tags: mysql

i want to update data on mysql table, this table have 2.258.164 row
there is the query

```
select ch_0  
from bmkg.tb_datastore_2017 
WHERE id_station='150001' 
AND date_time<'2017-02-06 17:30:00' 
and DATE_FORMAT(`date_time`,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2017-02-06' 
order by date_time Desc limit 1
```

this query need 55-60 second, its to slowly, Please help me to optimize this..
Thank you,
Warmest regards,

Comment: which field type is **date_time** and show us the **SHOW CREATE TABLE tb_datastore_2017**

Comment: one Problem is the usage of **DATE_FORMAT(`date_time`,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2017-02-06'** so MySQL MUST convert each row to format that you give. This will be a FULL TABLE SCAN and cant use a index. If the date_time field from type **DATETIME** so you can use my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use **BETWEEN** to prevent a FULL TABLE SCAN

```
SELECT  ch_0  
FROM bmkg.tb_datastore_2017 
WHERE id_station='150001' 
AND `date_time` BETWEEN '2017-02-06 00:00:00' AND  '2017-02-06 17:30:00'
ORDER BY date_time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

please post also the **EXPLAIN** of my query to see if there are any INDEX

Comment: `SELECT  ch_0  
FROM bmkg.tb_datastore_2017 
WHERE id_station='150001' 
AND `date_time` BETWEEN '2017-02-06 00:00:00' AND  '2017-02-06 17:30:00'
ORDER BY date_time DESC
LIMIT 1`;

Comment: This one is more suitable.

Comment: @Sagar Gangwal - OK - i have it not seen - i changed in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ch_0  
FROM bmkg.tb_datastore_2017 
WHERE id_station='150001' 
AND `date_time` BETWEEN '2017-02-06 00:00:00' AND  '2017-02-06 17:30:00'
ORDER BY date_time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Please try this.And let me know how much time it took to execute with same data.
Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use like this :-

```
select ch_0  
from bmkg.tb_datastore_2017
WHERE id_station='150001'
AND date_time<'2017-02-06 17:30:00' and DATE(`date_time`) = '2017-02-06'
order by date_time Desc limit 1;
```

I too was stuck with such issue and using Date() function solved by problem or else you can share EXPLAIN plan for your query so that we can analyse more.

Thanks,

Comment: you use DATE function in where, so its a full table scan